# How to send soap request with SHA2 and TLS version 1.2

Tags: php, soap, sha, tls1.2

I just wanted to send Soap request to the soap server using `SHA2` and `TLS1.2` but it's showing below error when trying to create soap client

**Error**

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://example.com/wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://example.com/wsdl"

**Code**

```
$url = 'https://example.com/wsdl';

$client = new SoapClient(
            $url,
            array(
              'ssl_method' => SOAP_SSL_METHOD_TLS,
              'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
              'stream_context'=> stream_context_create(
                array(
                  'ssl'=> array(
                    'crypto_method' => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT,
                    'ciphers' => 'SHA2',
                    'verify_peer'=>false,
                    'verify_peer_name'=>false, 
                    'allow_self_signed' => true //can fiddle with this one.
                  )
                )
              )
            )
          );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have solved by adding `SHA256` in `ciphars`. Actually **SHA2** has 4 kinds of hash functions: `SHA224`, `SHA256`, `SHA384` and `SHA512`.

**Changes**

```
'ciphers' => 'SHA256',
```

*Answering own question is little odd for me but it can help other devs.*

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have a certificate to place in the ssl array?

```
'cafile' => $certFile
```

Comment: I want to use `TLS1.2` instead of `SSL`